# NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/TypeAdapterFactory in Vaadin chart

Tags: java, charts, gson, noclassdeffounderror, vaadin7

I am just trying to implement simple bar chart with vaadin chart.
just as tutorial in below rank, I wrote code.

Link : http://demo.vaadin.com/charts/#BasicBar

But when I trying to extend, since there was no such class 'AbstractVaadinChartExample', I just make that method public static.

below is what I have done.

1. I downloaded vaadin chart 1.1.5.jar
2. I put that in my vaadin 7 project
3. I did not edit original code except added a line in the last. layout.addComponent(BasicBar.getChart());
4. My BasicBar.java is just same with that upper link, but I did not extend anything and made getChart() method to 'public static'.
5. Now I got 'NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/TypeAdapterFactory' error:-(

I can not understand, because I have done nothing with gson something.

My code like :

```
package org.owls.chart;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.vaadin.addon.charts.Chart;
import com.vaadin.addon.charts.model.ChartType;
import com.vaadin.addon.charts.model.Configuration;
import com.vaadin.addon.charts.model.HorizontalAlign;
import com.vaadin.addon.charts.model.Labels;
import com.vaadin.addon.charts.model.LayoutDirection;
import com.vaadin.addon.charts.model.Legend;
import com.vaadin.addon.charts.model.ListSeries;
import com.vaadin.addon.charts.model.PlotOptionsBar;
import com.vaadin.addon.charts.model.Title;
import com.vaadin.addon.charts.model.Tooltip;
import com.vaadin.addon.charts.model.VerticalAlign;
import com.vaadin.addon.charts.model.XAxis;
import com.vaadin.addon.charts.model.YAxis;
import com.vaadin.ui.Component;

public class BasicBar {
    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    public static Component getChart () {
        Chart chart = new Chart(ChartType.BAR);
        Configuration config = chart.getConfiguration();

        config.setTitle("basic chart");
        config.setSubTitle("2014.02.14");

        //X 
        XAxis xAxis = new XAxis();
        xAxis.setCategories("A", "B", "C", "D", "E");
        xAxis.setTitle("xTitle");
        config.addxAxis(xAxis);

        //Y 
        YAxis yAxis = new YAxis();
        yAxis.setMin(0);
        Title tile = new Title("y title");
        tile.setVerticalAlign(VerticalAlign.HIGH);
        yAxis.setTitle(tile);
        config.addyAxis(yAxis);

        Tooltip toolTip = new Tooltip();
        //???
        toolTip.setFormatter("this.series.name : + ': ' + this.y +' millions'");
        config.setTooltip(toolTip);

        //plot
        PlotOptionsBar plot = new PlotOptionsBar();
        //????
        plot.setDataLabels(new Labels(true));
        config.setPlotOptions(plot);

        Legend legend = new Legend();
        legend.setLayout(LayoutDirection.VERTICAL);

        legend.setHorizontalAlign(HorizontalAlign.RIGHT);
        legend.setVerticalAlign(VerticalAlign.TOP);
        legend.setX(-100);
        legend.setY(100);

        legend.setFloating(true);
        legend.setBorderWidth(1);
        legend.setBackgroundColor("#FFFFFF");
        legend.setShadow(true);

        config.setLegend(legend);

        config.disableCredits();

        List series = new ArrayList();
        series.add(new ListSeries("Year 1800", 107, 31, 635, 203, 2));
        series.add(new ListSeries("Year 1900", 133, 156, 947, 408, 6));
        series.add(new ListSeries("Year 2008", 973, 914, 4054, 732, 34));
        config.setSeries(series);

        chart.drawChart(config);
        return chart;
    }
}
```

How can I fix it?
Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

NoClassDefFoundError will arrive when your JAR is not referenced by the project. With the minor code change you have made, I don't think it will lead to the NoClassDefFoundError.

Can you please provide more info:

1. Is it simple Java project or web app?
2. You have added the JAR, but did you explicitely put it in the classpath using "Build classpath" in eclipse?
3. Without your minor changes, will the program runs successfully?

Comment: Thanks, Nikhil. I will give you infos that you have required. answer for #1 is just 'vaadin project 7.X'.(It is from Vaadin eclipse plug-in) #2 - of course, I already add build path of jar file to my project, So I could make source code with no compile error. #3 - Can not try, because the demo site does not provide full source code. They just show a Class definition.(You can check it with Link that I provided in post)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need this Jar loading: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/Downloadgson221jar.htm

It's not mentioned in the Stripe setup guidelines, installing this Jar resolved this error message for me if anyone else encounters this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Vaadin is GWT based so I suspect you are running a development server.

If so, add the gson path to you -Xbootclasspath

```
-Xbootclasspath/p:/somepath/libraries-master/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.48/lib/override/appengine-dev-jdk-overrides.jar:/p:/somepath/war/WEB-INF/lib/gson-2.2.4.jar
```

In Eclipse, look under run configurations --> Arguments --> VM Arguments

If you are launching the development server by Ant or another script, you will have to adjust the -Xbootclasspath there.